# javascript change element background

Tags: javascript

This is the HTML

```
<p>texjksdgfjl sdjfg sjdfg</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>texjksdgfjl sdjfg sjdfg</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>texjksdgfjl sdjfg sjdfg</p>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); 

for (var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
{ 
    var text = d[i].textContent;

    if (text.length===1){
        d[i].style.background ='blue';
    }
    else {
        d[i].setAttribute("backgroundColor", "red");
    }
}
```

(Obviously) I can do what I want to do - different background for p elements that contain some text as opposed to p elements which are generated as < p > & nbsp; < /p >

But why doesn't the setAttribute work?
I must be missing something very simple, but for the life of me I cannot imagine what it is.
Pure JS please, no jQuery, no MooTools, no other library.

Here is the test fiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/flish/3Lze5/)

Comment: I change it in the fiddle : `d[i].setAttribute("style", "background-color:red");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the `setAttribute` function doesn't do what you think it does.

If you inspect the elements in your jsfiddle, you see this:

```
... <p backgroundcolor="red" ...>
```

and this is *definitely* not what you want. What you want is something like this:

```
setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
```

so it will transform into

```
... <p style="background-color: red;" ...>
```

Answer (score 3):

`backgroundColor` isn't an attribute on HTML elements.  You can use `bgcolor`, but its really better to do this with CSS.

You can add a class to the node like this:

`d[i].className += " myClass";`

and then set a CSS rule

```
.myClass
{
  backgroundColor: "red"

}
```

Or if you insist on hardwiring it to the DOM you can use

```
d[i].style.backgroundColor =  "red"
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. My problem was not exactly handwriting attributes tag by tag, just the fact that I didn't seem to understand setAttribute

Comment: It understands setAttribute, backgroundColor is just not a valid attribute.  It's a style.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
d[i].style.setProperty("background", "red");
```

Instead of

```
d[i].setAttribute("backgroundColor", "red");
```

Comment: @flish I think this is the solution that less modify your original code

Answer (score 0):

Assming Page instead of your element, you can read the below tutorial to change the background via javascript:

http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/changing-background-color-using-javascript-and-jquery/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changebackground() {
            var colors = ["#0099cc","#c0c0c0","#587b2e",
"#990000","#000000","#1C8200","#987baa","#464646",
"#AA8971","#1987FC","#99081E"];

            setInterval(function() {
                var bodybgarrayno = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
                var selectedcolor = colors[bodybgarrayno];
                document.body.style.background = selectedcolor;
            }, 3000);
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do that:

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); 

for (var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
{ 
    var text = d[i].textContent;

    if (text.length===1){
        d[i].style.background ='blue';
    }
    else {
        d[i].style.background ='red';
    }
}
```

or

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); 

for (var i=0;i<d.length;i++)
{ 
    var text = d[i].textContent;

    if (text.length===1){
        d[i].style.background ='blue';
    }
    else {
        d[i].setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lze5/6/