# Randomize background img with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have working code, that randomly changes background of the `body` with my gif's.

```
var totalCount = 11;
function ChangeIt() {
  var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
  document.body.background = '/static/img/'+num+'.gif';
  document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";
  }
window.onload = ChangeIt;
```

Now I want to use it with another HTML element, one of the div's, for example. Changing `document.body.background` to `document.getElementById('id').background` doesn't work. How should I change the code?

Comment: I think this will be of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295381/javascript-change-element-background

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
document.getElementById('id').style.backgroundImage = "url('/static/img/" + num + ".gif')";
```

Also, the RNG with `Math.ceil()` means that images are based on `1` not on `0`:

```
1.gif
2.gif
...
11.gif
```

If this is not the case use `Math.floor()`:

```
0.gif
1.gif
...
10.gif
```

Depending on what the element is, you may need to set its dimensions (width and height). This is an example HTML element:

```
<div id="imagediv" style="width: 320px; height: 640px; background-repeat: repeat;"></div>
```

This the resulting code:

```
var totalCount = 11;

window.onload = function () {
  var num, node;

  num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * totalCount);
  node = document.getElementById("imagediv");

  node.style.backgroundImage = "url('/static/img/" + num + ".gif')";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be the correct syntax:

```
document.getElementById('id').style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.background` mostly worked for body background but not other html elements.So used this `document.getElementById('id').style.backgroundImage = "url(..)";`

```
var totalCount = 11;
function ChangeIt() {
  var divs =document.getElementById('id');
  var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
  divs.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/static/img/'+num+'.gif)';
  divs.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";
  divs.style.height = "300px"; //testing
  }
window.onload = ChangeIt;
```